# How do Steam Vent and Esper Dash interact?

Tags: flash-duel

When Bal-Bas-Beta and Setsuki Hiruki are playing against each other, the moves Steam Vent and Esper Dash have directly conflicting actions.

Steam Vent:

> Start of your turn: Push an opponent from a dark space away from you one space. That opponent **can't dashing strike** on his next turn.

Esper Dash:

> You move: You may move again **or dashing strike**.

If I use Steam Vent against my opponent, can he move and use Esper Dash to dashing strike me anyway? Or, if he uses Esper Dash, is he required to take the extra move action, since he can't dashing strike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Sirlin (the creator of the game):

> In all my games and also in MtG:
>
> If an ability says "You can do X" and another ability says "You can't do X," then "You **can't** do X" takes precedence.

This means that Steam Vents **would** prevent Setsuki from using her Esper Dash to use a dashing strike on the next turn.

Note: Sirlin's answer was originally posted [here](http://www.fantasystrike.com/forums/index.php?threads/how-do-steam-vent-and-esper-dash-interact.7542/#post-225731), but these forums have since been removed.